# Do you have to kill the High Dragon after the Urn of Sacred Ashes quest?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

So I've got my pinch of ashes, and I've got the "I'd like to meet an angry dragon now, please" horn. Having been grilled a couple of times now, I'm curious:

1. Do I have to kill the High Dragon?
2. If I opt not to do so, can I do it later, once I've found some Tier 10 Asbestos Underpants of    Well-Placed Drainage?

Comment: `Tier 10 Asbestos Underpants of Well-Placed Drainage` is that a DLC download? Or are they imported from Orlais? I could use a pair of those.

Comment: @glasnt: In Dragon Age? DLC of course!

Comment: It's probably like $10US, right? This is the same game that tried to charge people for April Fools gag gifts :/

Comment: /me tosses an angry dragon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to kill it at all. There is good loot available, and the scales of the dragon can be made into exceptional armor by the armorsmith (Master Wade in Denerim). If you so choose, you can definitely come back and try it. The best armor against it, however, is the armor you make from its scales. =P

Assuming you're a decent level, with good gear, the fight isn't too hard. Quaff some warmth potions, and beat the crap out of it. It's basically the same fight as the archdemon (so a good practice run) except not as tough, and without all the jumping around that the archdemon does.

Healing is critically important, so you know, make sure you've got Wynne, and that she doesn't get eaten early.

Comment: Haha, the irony of the dragon armour... Does the drake scale armour have similar benefits? Thanks.

Comment: @stuart: It does actually, it's just not as good as the big dragon armor, so if you want to run to Denerim and get some drake armor made before you tackle the big guy, it will have some benefit.

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to kill the dragon.

You can return to that place and kill the dragon at any time, until you initiate the final part of the story. That point is pretty obvious so feel free to get some better equipment and come back to slay the dragon.